# Reset dropdown Filters in React

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

In [this example from the docs of redux-forms](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/selectingformvalues/), `reset` is received as a prop from the parent component. Upon hitting the **Clear Values** button, `reset` is called, which resets the dropdown option to the default.

What could be inside the `reset` function? In other words, how react programmatically access the `<option>` element and changes its value?

Answer (score 0):

The `reset` is available as a prop to that form when you decorate it with `reduxForm({...})` as shown in the docs. That is, you don't have to write your own `reset()` and pass it down as a prop to the form component.

Answer (score 0):

> In other words, how react programmatically access the `<option>`
>   element and changes its value?

It doesn't... React doesn't work that way.

Consider

```
class Select extends React.Component {
  state = { selectedValue, options: [] }

  render() {
    return (
      <select>
        { this.state.options.map(mOption => {
          return 
          (
            <option 
              value={mOption.value}
              selected={selectedValue === mOption.value}
            >
              { option.label }
            </option>
          )
        }) }
      </select>
    )
  }
}
```

kind of a naive (and partial) implementation of what a `select` component would look like. in this case, a `reset` method would just reset `state` of the component, and react would resolve the DOM based on the new state. Redux is just a global state store - everything is more or less the same except state is mapped into props.